# Set datetime shows wrong date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two radio buttons to select a time range.

These two options are available:

**0:00 - 0:00 (24h)**

**6:00 - 6:00 (24h)**

And this is my jQ function:

```
$('.btn-time').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var a = new Date($('#ipDateTimeFrom').val());
    var b = new Date($('#ipDateTimeTo').val());
    switch(value) {
        case '0':
            a.setUTCHours(0);
            a.setUTCMinutes(0);
            a.setUTCSeconds(0);
            b.setUTCHours(0);
            b.setUTCMinutes(0);
            b.setUTCSeconds(0);
            break;
        case '6':
            a.setUTCHours(6);
            a.setUTCMinutes(0);
            a.setUTCSeconds(0);
            b.setUTCHours(6);
            b.setUTCMinutes(0);
            b.setUTCSeconds(0);
            break;
    }

    $('#ipDateTimeFrom').val(a.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace( /\..+/g, ''));
    $('#ipDateTimeTo').val(b.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace( /\..+/g, ''));
});
```

If I switch between 0:00 and 6:00 the date change from 2016-06-07 00:00:00 to 2016-06-06 06:00:00 and I dont know why. The Date day ist untouched.

Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/geliyenego/edit?html,js,output) to point out the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you mix local time with UTC time, and you are probably living in a UTC+something timezone.

More precisely, the string value you read from the input element and convert to date is interpreted as a local date/time. But in UTC format this is a few hours earlier, and so when you start truncating the date to 0:00 all is still OK, but then the input also gets 0:00, which in UTC is a few hours earlier, i.e. in the previous day. So the next time you perform a truncation to 6:00 it will be 6:00 the previous day.

So you should stick in all operations with either UTC or local dates. Here is how you make the input strings to be interpreted as UTC, so that all operations are in UTC:

```
var a = new Date($('#ipDateTimeFrom').val().replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
var b = new Date($('#ipDateTimeTo').val().replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
// etc.
```

Of course this assumes the date/time entered follows a certain format. But you'll get the idea. The `Z` at the end makes it UTC.

Comment: Hi @trincot, thanks for your answer. The timezone cast works well :-)

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself a life of pain, use moment.js. It makes the parsing and formatting so much easier

```
$('.btn-time').on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var a = new Date($('#ipDateTimeFrom').val());
        var b = new Date($('#ipDateTimeTo').val());
        var newA, newB;
        switch(value) {
            case '0':
                newA = moment(a).startOf('day');
                newB = moment(b).startOf('day');
                break;
            case '6':
                newA = moment(a).startOf('day').hours(6);
                newB = moment(b).startOf('day').hours(6);
                break;
        }

        $('#ipDateTimeFrom').val(newA.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ipDateTimeTo').val(newB.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/gecahaquqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hi @derp, I never worked with moment.js before. But it looks really interessting.

Comment: @nagazi Moment is a very straight forward tool and it does make working with dates a whooole lot easier. but always think before including big js files into your project, if you only need a tiny bit of date-work then perhaps it's better to just struggle a few extra minutes and save the user some load time :)

Comment: It is a intranet application. I used the minified moment lib. But thanks for the information :-)